# Override function without creating new class C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, overriding, abstract

I have the following scenario :

```
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    public virtual Foo()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

And i have this class stored in another class

```
SomeClass InstanceOfTheClass { get; set; }
```

How can I override only the function `Foo` from `SomeClass` without creating a new class inheriting from `SomeClass` and then overriding the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way.

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class.

Besides, `SomeClass` is abstract, you wouldn't be able to create an instance of it anyway =/

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the behaviour that you want to copy, you could define an interface `IFoo` and implement that in your class.

Comment: Can you provide an example ? I'm pretty sure after this i will end up in the same situation..

Comment: As mentioned by @Renato Medeiros, it is not possible to override without a derived class. So abstract the Foo behaviour into an interface IFoo. You can then implement IFoo in where you mentioned "another class". That way you don't have to create a concrete class for the abstract one (I mean the abstract class is not in the picture). Hopefully helps, but if not please provide some context.

Comment: Agreed with @Anwar Husain regarding use of interfaces. If you can provide more detail about the concrete problem, perhaps a detailed answer can be provided.